# Where can I find the Salesforce User Password?

Tags: user-management, passwords

I m looking for the Salesforce User password contain in which object. have needed for manage admin for redirecting specific page base on that id and password.? please give solution.

Comment: Why do you need the password to perform your redirect? What is your page meant to do?

Comment: I have to assign different page for different user which is in same organization.so think for that? if u have any other idea than please guid me how to do that

Comment: Yes, but why do you need the password? Surely the User Id/Name is enough to identify a user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get the user password for security reasons. You can only reset it if you need to but there is no way to get nor the password or the hash.